# WP8.1 Gestures from Touchscreen - Native Methods

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When searching on how to do so i am digging into tons of code samples which use the Windows Phone Toolkit, GestureReceiver or Silverlight solutions. Some don't even support 2-finger slides and other common gestures.

As i understood the ms-docs, even 2-finger gestures are supported with native elements now. Could somebody point me out how to start receiving gesture input with methods like **ManipulationStarted** and **ManipulationCompleted** in VB . NET? Thanks!